# Running janus, webRtc on react native webview doesn't work

Tags: react-native, webview, janus-gateway

I'm trying to run the demo video call of Janus: https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videocalltest.html
using react-native-community/react-native-webview but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, native webview does not work with webrtc, eventhough safari on ios and chrome on android does.

For native mobile app support you can use react-native-webrtc node module

We were doing this also but are currently looking at Jitsi meet as alternative